# sqlalchemy table reflection not setting the default charset

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a default character set for a sqlalchemy table built reflectively.  Some of our tables have columns which are latin1, and some are utf8.

I could create a table manually as follows...

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import VARCHAR
table = Table('foo', meta,
Column('col1', VARCHAR(200, charset='latin1'))
)
```

However, if I try and reflectively create that from a database...

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost:3306/bar')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
records = Table('foo', metadata, autoload=True)
records.columns['col1'].type.charset #Is not set
```

Does anyone have an idea how to force the reflection to pick up the column character sets?

Comment: Limitations of reflection, not sure if character set is in that... https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/931be6126718bbfc9a0bcf9ad92b535fb4273a0b/doc/build/core/reflection.rst#limitations-of-reflection

Comment: vender specific types shows the creation of the column charset type... http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#vendor-specific-types